# Select random rows according to a given criteria PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I have table `user` with ten million rows. It has fields: `id int4 primary key`, `rating int4`, `country varchar(32)`, `last_active timestamp`. It has gaps in identifiers.
The task is to select five random users for a given country which were active in a period of last two days and has rating in a given range. 
Is there a tricky way to select them faster than the query below?

```
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE last_active > '2020-04-07'
    AND rating between 200 AND 280
    AND country = 'US'
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 5
```

It thought about this query:

```
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE last_active > '2020-04-07'
    AND rating between 200 AND 280
    AND country = 'US'
    AND id > (SELECT random()*max(id) FROM user)
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 5
```

but the problem is that there lots of inactive users with small identifier values, the majority of new users are in the end of the id range. So, this query would select some users too often.

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the current plan.  The best way to speed this up is likely to make the existing query faster, rather than trying to find a less-correct query.

Comment: Here is the [output](https://pastebin.com/yACWZn8e) from production DB. I've already found it is run on default settings. I've also excluded `country` column from the query  because it is in development code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the EXPLAIN plan, your table is large.  About 2 rows per page.  Either it is very bloated, or the rows themselves are very wide.

The key to getting good performance is probably to get it to use an index-only scan, by creating an index which contains all 4 columns referenced in your query.  The column tested for equality should come first.  After that, you have to choose between your two range-or-inequality queried columns ("last_active" or "rating"), based on whichever you think will be more selective.  Then you add the other range-or-inequality and the id column to the end, so that an index-only scan can be used.  So maybe `create index on app_user (country, last_active, rating, id)`.  That will probably be good enough.

You could also try a GiST index on those same columns.  This has the theoretical advantage that the two range-or-inequality restrictions can be used together in defining what index pages to look at.  But in practise GiST indexes have very high overhead, and this overhead would likely exceed the theoretical benefit.

If the above aren't good enough, you could try partitioning. But how exactly you do that should be based on a holistic view of your application, not just one query.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I'll think how to solve the task on app level, not on dbms.